# How does the getblocktemplate request rate correlate with a miner's hashrate?

Tags: mining-pools, hashpower, getblocktemplate

What is the relationship between a miner's hashrate and the [getblocktemplate (GBT)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate) request rate?

<sup>(The question here, "[How does the rate of getwork requests correlate with the hashrate of a miner?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3427/4334)," discusses [getwork](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork), but that's outdated.)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no relationship. With a single block template mining software can create a limitless amount of work by modifying the extranonce, the only reason they would need to update to a new one is to include transactions that have just arrived, or when someone else has found a block. The reason `GetWork` rates varied was that each request was only valid for a single 2**32 nonce range, which a modern ASIC miner can exhaust in milliseconds.